# How to set Boost UDP socket message QoS flags

Tags: c++, sockets, boost, udp

### How do I set a Boost UDP socket messages QoS flags?

To be clear I'm trying to set [these](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4#DSCP) bits or the "Traffic Class" for [ipv6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6_packet) in a UDP message header before I send it.

I've look through the [UDP Socket](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ip__udp/socket.html) documentation but can't find anything related to [DiffSer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiated_services).

I noticed a [`message_flags`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_datagram_socket/message_flags.html) and [`service_type`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_datagram_socket/service_type.html) types but can't find anything useful about what they do or how to use them. Could either of those set the flags I'm interested in?